# Proof with fields.

Tags: abstract-algebra

I'm stuck with a problem on my Algebra study.

> Let $R$ be a commutative ring with more than one element. Prove that
>   if for every nonzero element $a \in R$, we have $aR=R$, then $R$ is a
>   field.

I've been brainstorming for a while. So, this is what I have so far:

Since $aR=R$  $\forall a \neq 0 \in R,r \in R$, then $ar \in  R$ (obvious step).
But since the subset of a non-zero is contained in $R$, then all elements $a$ are in $R$. (I think this might be important).

If $R$ had the inverse element $r^{-1}$ $ \forall r$, it would be trivial, but it's not a ring requirement to have a multiplicative inverse (unit). So I'm stuck here. I don't think I can guarantee that ar will ever produce the identity element.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments I ignored some of the finer details of the question in my original answer, so here is a fixed version:

---

As dREaM pointed out in the comments every such ring has a unit: For a fixed non-zero element $a \in R$ we have $a R = R$, so there exists some element $1 \in R$ with $a \cdot 1 = a$ (because $R$ contains more than one element such a non-zero element does exists). For an arbitrary element $b \in R = aR = Ra$ there exists some $r \in R$ with $b = ra$, which is why
$$
 b \cdot 1 = ra \cdot 1 = ra = b.
$$
So $1$ is the claimed unit. Notice that because $R$ contains more then one element we have $1 \neq 0$.

For every non-zero $a \in R$ we have $aR = R$, so in particular there exists some $b \in R$ with $ab = 1$. This shows every non-zero element in $R$ is invertible. So $R$ is a unitial, commutative ring with $1 \neq 0$, such that every element $a \in R$ is invertible, i.e. $R$ is a field.

Comment: Thank you very much. It's easier than I expected. I always make too much out of these exercises.

Comment: What is your counter example if $R$ doesn't contain 1? (I agree that it is false in this case. However, one of AJ44 hypothesis is that the ring isn't $0$, so the "stupid" counter example doesn't work. The examples of natural non-unit rings I can think of - compactly supported functions on the reals, for example - don't satisfies AJ44's property. So ... what ring are you thinking of?)

Comment: @AreaMan what counterexample are you thinking of? I am pretty sure no other counterexample exists.

Comment: @dREaM I wasn't thinking of one, it just seemed likely to be false. But maybe it isn't?

Comment: @AreaMan take $a\in R$. Notice there is an element $e\in R$ so that $ae=a$.  We now prove $re=r$ for every $r$ in $R$: notice by hypothesis $r$ can be written as $za$. so $re=(za)e=z(ae)=za=r$. Therefore $e$ is the multplicative identity we wanted.

Comment: @dREaM Nice. Thanks.

Comment: Please, fix your initial statement: the statement is true even if $R$ is not assumed to have an identity (provided, of course, it's not the zero ring).

Comment: I have to admit that I originally didn’t notice these finer details of the question and formulated my assumptions in a rather bad way. I fixed my answer and added @dREaM’s proof of the existence of the unit.

Answer (score 4):

Hint: If $aR = R$, then in particular there is some $r$ so that $ar = 1$.

Exercise (developing this idea): If $R$ is a domain, and also a contains a field $k$ as a subring, so that $R$ is a finite dimensional vector space over that field (the field $k$ acts on $R$ by multiplication), then $R$ is a field.

Comment: Well, that was quick. I really must brush up on my algebra knowledge! Thanks a lot.